# Cannot connect to OpenVPN server under Ubuntu 14.04 (from terminal), but all is fine in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, terminal

In Windows all is ok.
In Ubuntu I run command

> sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn

and get

> TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
>   
>  TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

What should I to do to fix this?
(already tried to change nobind -> local ip in client.ovpn, no sucess)

> 2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]188.226.96.50:56532, sid=b8f1f244 63645f4e'
>   2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 OpenSSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol'
>   2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error'
>   2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error'
>   2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed'
>   2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting'

https://jsfiddle.net/8rrz7bLj/ client.ovpn
https://jsfiddle.net/14njzgrt/ server settings, found by

> locate .conf | grep openvpn

command

Comment: Look in the logs on the server

Comment: @user449299 added message from the log.

Comment: please edit your server and client config into the question.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider added both